# D3: setting scale on choropleth map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have hunted around the darkest corners of the web for one hour but have not found a satisfactory answer to my question, or indeed a satisfactory demonstration.

I am trying to amend M Bostock's [US unemployment choropleth map](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) that applies [D3 scale chromatic](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic). I am stumped. I am unable to amend the script to work with my data.

I have values ranging from 2,000 to 150,000. I would like to set up ten 'buckets' as follows:

```
[2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 30000, 50000, 100000]
```

How would I need to amend the below script so that my colours are displayed properly when I feed the numbers?

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([1, 10])
    .rangeRound([600, 860]);

var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain(d3.range(2, 10))
    .range(d3.schemeBlues[9]);
```

I have worked out that 'rangeRound' affects the placement of the legend on the page. Other than that, I am stuck.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm happy to see that you're a polite person that says *"thank you"*, but I edited your question for a reason. Please, don't roll it back. Have a look here for more information: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379/5768908

Comment: Gerardo, I didn't stop to notice who edited my question. Am a bit surprised it is you given how helpful and on the money with your knowledge you have always been. This isn't your most helpful contribution, boss. I mean this respectfully.

Comment: Did you read the link I provided? Editing questions to remove "hello", "thank you" and user names is something extremely common here at S.O. However, if you are upset, I'll just roll it back and, also, delete my answer.

Comment: I have read your link, and my answer to you above was polite (a trend, as you have yourself conceded). May I remind you that you and I hail from cultures where politeness has not been totally eradicated in the name of expediency. Removing your answer below was silly, especially since it was correct.

Comment: Incidentally, when I said 'this is not your most helpful contribution' I meant your editing of my question, and obviously not your answer (which again was 100% correct). If you would like to post it again, I shall accept it as the answer. Peace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is as follows:

```
var myDomain = [10000, 15000, 20000, 30000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 140000]

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(myDomain)
    .rangeRound([500, 860]);

var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain(myDomain)
    .range(d3.schemeOranges[8]);
```

Credit goes to Gerardo Furtado. An unexpected consequence of amending the script in this way is that the legend is now messed up and blown out of proportion. I have [posted a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138332/d3-scaling-legend-for-choropleth-map) where I highlight the issue.